# Mysql - Change verbose date format to Y-m-d

Tags: mysql, date, type-conversion

I'm working on a project which was apparently built by a total beginner. The date is being stored in a `varchar` column in the format 'Jan 20, 2010'. I need to convert this column to a `DATE` or `DATETIME` but when I do so (on a backup), the values becomes `0000-00-00`.

I tried to convert the values to proper format before changing the column type using `str_to_date()` and `DATE()` functions but both report invalid string format. Is it possible to convert this data to a valid date format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `STR_TO_DATE`, and update this column with a proper date value using the current text date.

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET new_date = STR_TO_DATE(old_date, '%b %e, %Y');
```

My guess is that either you are using the wrong format mask and/or some of your text dates have problems.  Here is a brief demo showing that the above logic works.

### Demo

Comment: Ah. I thought you need to provide the format that you want. Your code works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead.

```
UPDATE table_name
SET DATES =  DATE_FORMAT(DATES, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

I suggest to use another column to store the updated date value. I.E: `update tb_date set new_date_column = DATE_FORMAT(date_column, '%y-%m-%d');`

Check it out, Hope it'll work for you.